# How can I highlight the cells of a IKImageBrowserView on mouse over?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to provide some feedback when the mouse is over on one of the cells of an `IKImageBrowserView`.

Specifically, I'd like to resize the cell a little, to make it appear slightly larger on mouse-over. Alternatively, highlighting the background/border would be fine.

Unfortunately, `IKImageBrowserCell` is not a subclass of `NSCell`, but rather `NSObject`, and I can't find the solution in the APIs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try subclassing IKImageBrowserView and adding an [NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html) to the visible rect. You could then [implement -mouseMoved: to work with the tracking area](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH8-SW8) to locate the correct image cell using [-indexOfItemAtPoint:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004708-CH3-SW40) then get its frame by using [-itemFrameAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004708-CH3-SW41).

Rather than try to muck with IKImageBrowserView's black-box layers and drawing, you could add your own layer (or borderless window) above the newly-discovered frame and use standard animations to grow/shrink/animate/glow/shake/whatever this "cheat" cell. Let clicks "pass through" (and hide your "cheat" cell) so the normal drag-and-drop mechanism works the same. IKImageBrowserView has its own -setForegroundLayer: method that allows you to add an "overlay layer" - perfectly suited for this purpose, I'd imagine.

That'd be my first attempt at solving this problem if it were my own.

Comment: How can I add a NSTrackingArea to a IKImageBrowserView  if addTrackingArea: method is not available (it is not a view) ?

Comment: Err ... IKImageBrowserView *is* a view. It even has the word "View" in its name. It inherits directly *from* NSView, in fact, so -addTrackingArea: is available; it's just not in IKImageBrowserView reference (because it's in NSView reference). :-) You **definitely** need to spend more time learning how to traverse the API reference like a ninja as its inheritance (and a link to NSView) is right at the top of its reference page.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is already answered (without code though) but I also came across same requirement and I implemented it by subclassing IKImageBrowswerView. Below is my code and I hope it will help someone. To use it just set class of image browser view in xib/nib/storyboard to CustomIKImageBrowserView and add below classes to project.

```
     #import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
    #import "CustomizableNSView.h"
    @interface CustomIKImageBrowserView : IKImageBrowserView
    {
        NSTrackingArea *trackingArea;
        NSInteger lastHoverIndex;
        CustomizableNSView *hoverView ;
    }
    @end
```

And implementing class is:

```
#import "CustomIKImageBrowserView.h"

    @implementation CustomIKImageBrowserView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self addCustomTrackingAreaToChangeMouseCursor];
}

- (void) updateTrackingAreas {
    if (trackingArea)
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    [self addCustomTrackingAreaToChangeMouseCursor];
}

- (void) addCustomTrackingAreaToChangeMouseCursor{
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc]  initWithRect:self.bounds options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingMouseMoved owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void) mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSPoint currentPosition = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

    NSInteger idx  = [self indexOfItemAtPoint:currentPosition];
    if(idx != NSNotFound) {
        [[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] push];
        //NSLog(@"DslrIKImageBrowserView = %ld and %ld",idx,lastHoverIndex);
        if (lastHoverIndex == idx) {
            return;
        } else {
            if(hoverView)
                [hoverView removeFromSuperview];
        }

        lastHoverIndex = idx;
        IKImageBrowserCell *cell = [self cellForItemAtIndex:idx];
        NSRect r = cell.imageFrame;
        r.size.width = r.size.width + 6;
        r.size.height = r.size.height + 6;
        r.origin.x = r.origin.x - 3;
        r.origin.y = r.origin.y - 3 ;

        hoverView = [[CustomizableNSView alloc] initWithFrame:r];
        hoverView.borderColor   = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:136/255.0 green:185/255.0 blue:236/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        hoverView.borderRadious = 0;
        hoverView.borderWidth   = 6;
        hoverView.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:191.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.3];
        [self.superview addSubview:hoverView];

    } else
    {
        lastHoverIndex = -1;
        [[NSCursor arrowCursor] push];
        if(hoverView)
            [hoverView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    [[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] push];
}

- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    //[[NSCursor arrowCursor] push];
    lastHoverIndex = -1;
    if(hoverView) [hoverView removeFromSuperview];
} @end
```

And the CustomizableNSView is:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CustomizableNSView : NSView
{

}
@property (nonatomic) NSRect boundsToCustomize;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat borderRadious;
@property (nonatomic) NSColor *borderColor;
@property (nonatomic) NSColor *backgroundColor;


@end
=================
#import "CustomizableNSView.h"

@implementation CustomizableNSView


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSRect r = self.bounds;

    if(!NSIsEmptyRect(self.boundsToCustomize))
        r = self.boundsToCustomize;
    if(self.borderColor){
        NSBezierPath * bgPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: r xRadius: self.borderRadious yRadius: self.borderRadious];
        bgPath.lineWidth = self.borderWidth;
        NSAffineTransform * t = [NSAffineTransform transform];
        [t translateXBy: 0.5 yBy: 0.5];
        [bgPath transformUsingAffineTransform: t];
        //NSColor* rgbColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:101.0/255.0 green: 101.0/255.0  blue:101.0/255.0  alpha:0.5];
        [self.borderColor set];
        [bgPath stroke];

        if(self.backgroundColor){
            [self.backgroundColor set];
            [bgPath fill];
        }
    }


}
@end
```

I hope it will help someone and will speed up the development.